# JTextPane and XHTMLRenderer: When to use which

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, xhtmlrenderer

What are some situations that you would use XHTMLRenderer (flying saucer) over JTextPane with a HTMLDocument and vice versa? Is it mostly a matter of preference or are there certain cases that one is a more natural choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`HTMLDocument`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html) is part of the standard Java library, but it is limited to [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32). In contrast, [Flying Saucer](https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/feature-list.html) is an external dependency, but it includes "Strong support for the CSS 2.1 specification."